# Sending a pointer to an interface property in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pointers, reference, instance

Ok so I -roughly- want this code:

test1.m:

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
foo.x = 1.0f;

[staticClass bar:*foo.x];
```

staticClass.m:

```
-(void)bar:(float *)argVar
{
  *argVar += 1.0f;
}
```

So I'm pointing the argVar to a property of the Foo class. Obivously the current code doesn't work.

What's the proper syntax for/way to do this?

Comment: it shouldn't be `-(void)bar:(float *)argVar`, it should be `+(void) bar:(float *) argVar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that the proper way to do it is this:

```
float tmp = foo.x;
[staticClass bar:&temp];
foo.x = tmp;
```

and StaticClass.m should look like this:

```
+(void) bar:(float *) argvar // < not plus instead of minus, denotes static method
{
     *argVar = 1.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a property of `Foo`, not a variable. A property is just a short-hand for a pair of get/set methods. It has no address, as such, and so cannot be passed around as you are trying to do.

The simplest work-around is to go through a local variable:

```
float d = foo.x;
[staticClass bar:&d];
foo.x = d;
```

Also note that you use `&`, not `*`, to take the address of a variable.

Comment: They are floats, not doubles :)

Answer (score 0):

Options:

- change `Foo` such that it has a `float *` property
- change `+[staticClass bar:]` such that it takes and returns a float, updating your client code accordingly
- use `ivar_getOffset` to find the location of the instance variable backing `x` in your `Foo` instance